# Return null Future from Navigator.pop()

Tags: flutter, dart, null, navigator

I'm passing values from one page to another as mentioned in the official documentation. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

I implemented two different buttons.

1. Submit button which returns a list of String.
2. Close button which returns null.

   ```
                ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  _formKey.currentState?.save();
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    _formKey.currentState?.fields.forEach((key, value) {
                      // return a list with the names
                      widget._names.add(value.value);
                      print(widget._names);
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context, widget._names);
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Speichern & Zurück')),
            OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, null);
                },
                child: Text('Verwerfen & Zurück'))
   ```

The value is the return value of the Navigator.push() - method.

```
                            result = Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => PlayerNames(
                                    _currentBoySliderValue,
                                    _currentGirlSliderValue)));
```

I catch the null Future by simply checking:

```
                      if (result != null) {
                    // does not catch Future<dynamic> with null content 
                  }
```

Unfortunately, the Future (result) is only null if the Page PlayerNames() is never called, because pressing the Button which returns null, does not make the Future go null, but its content. This leads to the unintentional behaviour, that if the user inserts no data in the page and uses the button, which results in returning null my methods are called on a future with null values.

Is there any chance to set a Future to null, if the value that stores this information is the target?  I don't want to add code for checking if the values of the future are null because it's not always permitted to have null data.

Comment: You should add `await` while waiting for the response from `PlayerNames`. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: That worked, but I have no idea why. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Additionally I had to change the Future<dynamic> result  to List<String>? result;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `await` while waiting for the response from `PlayerNames`.

To return data from another screen in Flutter, you have to wait for the screen to finish and return data. `await` keyword waits for the screen to finish.

For further clarification, you can follow [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) link

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, instead return null, just return an empty array '[ ]' and then validate if the result is empty.

```
Navigator.pop(context, []);
```

```
      if (result.isEmpty()) {
    // do some stuff
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work, because returning an empty list is not always permitted. The content of widget._names can be empty, which would lead to a wrong assertion. I basically want the null button to be some sort of cancle option to jump out of the page without changing anything on the code or state.

Answer (score 0):

How about you change return data type to Map?

```
             ElevatedButton(
             onPressed: () async {
               _formKey.currentState?.save();
               if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                 _formKey.currentState?.fields.forEach((key, value) {
                   // return a list with the names
                   widget._names.add(value.value);
                   print(widget._names);
                 });
                 Navigator.pop(context, { 'isExistData': true, 'data': widget._names });
               }
             },
             child: Text('Speichern & Zurück')),
         OutlinedButton(
             onPressed: () {
               Navigator.pop(context, { 'isExistData': false });
             },
             child: Text('Verwerfen & Zurück'))
```

```
if (result['isExistData']) {
  // Do something
  var data = result['data']

}
```